# How to make windows 10 ask for file versioning like on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

On Windows 7, when copying a file, you could keep old file and the new file altogether as it proposes to increment file name version like file(2).txt

On Windows 10, I can't see the same, it just proposes to keep or replace, is there any option to get the same behavior as Windows 7 ?

Comment: If you are asking if you can change how Windows 10 presents this information, then you cannot do that, unless you replace File Explorer with a different shell.

Comment: @running.t thanks for the video: that was the answer.

Comment: @user75875: So I posted my comment as an answer. If you find it useful please upvote or accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think starting from Windows 8, if you are copying multiple files, you should see `Replace or skip files` pop-up window. Choose `Let me decide for each file` and then for each conflicting there will be question `Which file do you want to keep?`. Mark and select both files to keep old one and new one with changed name.

[This movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFxIPEDZCOA) shows full procedure.